# docker pull images error：microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 as build is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, .net-core

I met this problem:Error parsing reference: "microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 as build" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Comment: was this in a Dockerfile? can you paste file contents? what does "docker -v" say?

Comment: please give us details of the problem so that we can work with it. What command you exactly run? what is docker version?